# Ansible is failed for some of the servers while performing user add task

Tags: linux, ansible

Below is the error :

FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_pyt                                                                                                             hon": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "checksum": "2ca063f74f5a03d16fb6db0                                                                                                             dba613f2ec60f97b2", "msg": "Aborting, target uses selinux but python bindings (l                                                                                                             ibselinux-python) aren't installed!"}

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Did you really read the error message?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the indicated package on the target host before trying to manipulate user accounts.

On old RHEL/CentOS 7 systems you should install `libselinux-python`. On modern systems such as RHEL 8 and Fedora it is named `python3-libselinux`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, Ansible needs Python bindings for selinux on Linux systems.

For RHEL or Fedora,

```
yum install libselinux-python*
```

will install these for python3, and also python2 in the case of RHEL 7.

Comment: The old name `libselinux-python` does not work on RHEL 8 or Fedora.

Comment: The wildcard matches  libselinux-python3, which is still provided by python3-libselinux last I checked CentOS 8.

Comment: Not anymore in RHEL 8.4.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a version of ansible that use **python2.7** and also your OS is **centos 8**, follow the below structure:

```
pip2.7 install selinux
```

if you did not set your default python to version 2.7 (on target host):

```
cd /usr/bin/
# below command will create a symbolic link to python2.7
ln -s python2.7 python
```